# Are automatically generated GUIDs for types in .NET consistent?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

Are the automatically generated GUIDs for C# Types consistent? For example, if I get a GUID for my interface, IFoo (`typeof(IFoo).GUID`), the first time a run the program, will I get that same GUID everytime I run the program?

I have tested it locally on my machine, and it seems to always be the same, but I'm not sure if I can rely on it always being the same across machines.

Comment: I think that that GUID is not being generated at all, but was generated once and therefore it's always the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See: [System.Type.GUID stability](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/12/System.Type.GUID-stability.aspx). It appears that the current implementation of the method relies an internal call that is implemented by the CLR itself. Unless  Microsoft clarifies the contracts for the auto-generated Guids (the [**`Type.GUID`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.guid.aspx) documentation is currently silent on this issue), I wouldn't rely on the observed behaviour. To be sure about consistency, I recommend explicitly decorating the types in question with the [**`GuidAttribute`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid explicitly defining the GUID, but it seems as though that will be the safest route.

Comment: If you are curious, [here is the code in the CLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/7f7d8276e65059a37001aaa5ce9af7e82249f4a0/src/vm/methodtable.cpp#L7377) that Type.GUID is forwarding on to.

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented so i wouldn't completly rely on them, said that the implementation may or may not change in the future.