# How does C# generate GUIDs for Classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Apparently C# (or Visual Studio) generates a GUID for each class.  I can get the GUID using the following code:

```
Type myType = typeof(myObject);
Guid myGuid = (Guid)myType.GUID.
```

My question is when does this GUID change.  Is it generated based on a code change or is it based on class creation?  I'd appreciate a point towards some relevant documentation.

Thanks

Comment: There is another SO question relating to this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649883/are-automatically-generated-guids-for-types-in-net-consistent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is documentation on how C#/.Net "automatically" generates the GUID for type.

If you need the Guid to stay persistent (or control it in some other way) you should use [GuidAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of letting system to create one for you:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute("00000000-0000-0000-feed-000000000000")]
class Test1{};
```